# event object for <div>

Tags: javascript, html

I saw  a piece pf code to implement thumbnails;

```
 <div id="divId" onclick="changeImageOnClick(event)">
        <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Hydrangeas.jpg" />
        <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Jellyfish.jpg" />
        <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Koala.jpg" />
        <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Penguins.jpg" />
        <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Tulips.jpg" />
 </div>
```

so when I click the first image for example, when I use event.target.tagName, is it "img" or "div", I mean is the event object a div object or img object? I think it should be div object,but actually it is img object, so in this case, how can I get the div object?
here is the complete code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .imgStyle
        {
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            border:3px solid grey;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="mainImage" style="border:3px solid grey" 
         src="/Images/Hydrangeas.jpg" height="500px" width="540x"/>
    <br />
    <div id="divId" onclick="changeImageOnClick(event)">
        <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Hydrangeas.jpg" />
        <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Jellyfish.jpg" />
        <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Koala.jpg" />
        <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Penguins.jpg" />
        <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Tulips.jpg" />
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function changeImageOnClick(event)
        {
            event = event || window.event;
            var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;

            if (targetElement.tagName == "IMG")
            {
                mainImage.src = targetElement.getAttribute("src");
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

so the code use :

```
if(targetElement.tagName == "IMG")
```

if the target is a div object, shouldn't it be targetElement.tagName == "DIV"?

Comment: Looking at your example, the onclick is on the div element meaning that `event.target.tagName` will equal 'DIV' (tagName is upcased in the event).

Comment: `console.log` it, of course it's the `div`, the event is binded to the `div`

Comment: `The EventTarget object represents the target to which an event is dispatched when something has occurred.` [Read More](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-eventtarget)

Comment: look at the other propertied in the event object. `console.log(event)`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this was a little surprising to me but because of event bubbling the event.target.tagName is IMG. To get the parent you can call `event.target.parentNode.tagName`.

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/iamjpg/rwasdd90/ (Ignore broken images - just click them for output).

```
<script>
  var changeImageOnClick = function(e) {
    document.getElementById('event').innerHTML = "Event Object: " + e.target.tagName;
    document.getElementById('binding').innerHTML = "Parent Object: " + e.target.parentNode.tagName;
  }

</script>

<div id="divId" onclick="changeImageOnClick(event)">
  <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Hydrangeas.jpg" />
  <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Jellyfish.jpg" />
  <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Koala.jpg" />
  <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Penguins.jpg" />
  <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Tulips.jpg" />
</div>

<br />
<br />

<div id="event"></div>
<div id="binding"></div>
```

Comment: do you mean it is event bubbling? what I don't understand is the onclick event is in <div>, so the target should be div element,why the target become img object?

Answer (score 0):

event.target is a reference to the object that dispatched the event. That event bubbles up the DOM and your div handles the event.

This is actually a pattern referred to as event delegation.

In your javascript code in your changeImageOnClick function, if you want to reference your div then you can use the `this` key word.

Examples using `this`:

if you want to use inline event declarations, like you have above:

```
<div id="divId" onclick="changeImageOnClick(this, event)">
    <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Hydrangeas.jpg" />
    <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Jellyfish.jpg" />
    <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Koala.jpg" />
    <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Penguins.jpg" />
    <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Tulips.jpg" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
      var changeImageOnClick = function(elem, e) {
          var clickedElementName = e.target.tagName;
          var containingElementName = elem.tagName;
      }
</script>
```

Or, you could take a more unobtrusive approach like this. Notice that the `onclick` event is defined for the div element in javascript only and not in your HTML:

```
<div id="divId">
    <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Hydrangeas.jpg" />
    <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Jellyfish.jpg" />
    <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Koala.jpg" />
    <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Penguins.jpg" />
    <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Tulips.jpg" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("divId").onclick = function(e) {
        var clickedElementName = e.target.tagName;
        var containingElementName = this.tagName;
    };
</script>
```

Comment: @JustSomeDude what I don't understand is the code use if(targetElement.tagName == "IMG"), and when you use div to wrap some images, when you click one image, should the event object be img object or div object?

Comment: @epascarello you are right, I should've included examples. Updated to include them now, maybe it will help someone in the future.

Comment: @grooveline as I mentioned above event.target is a reference to the object that dispatched the event, in this instance the event is click and the element that was clicked is an `img` element. Essentially, the containing div is clicked, but it was clicked on where one of it's child nodes existed, so the event bubbles up from the child node to the parent div node. If the div was clicked, but an area of the div was clicked outside of an img tag, then the event.target would be the div, not the img element, due to the fact it was the div that dispatched the onclick event.